# Map two arrays given a map of possible mappings

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, arrays

Given two integer arrays `a` and `b` and a map `m` which for each element `e` of the array `a` returns an array `p` of possible mappings, map every `e` of `a` to an element `k` of `b` so that `m[e]` contains `k`, no element of `a` or `b` is mapped twice and the number of non-mapped integers in `a` is minimal. Note that both `a` and `b` may have repetitive elements.

For example:

> a = [1,2], b = [3,4], m = [1 => [3,4], 2 => [3]]

We see that 1 can be mapped both to 3 and to 4. However since we want the number of mapped elements to be maximal we must map 1 to 4 because 2 can only be mapped to 3. So the result here would be:

> 1 => 4, 2 => 3

So far I've only come up with the bruteforce solution which is to just try every possible mapping for every value in `a`. However this solution has a time complexity of `O(n) = !n * k` where `n` is the number of elements in `a` and `k` is the number of possible mappings.

How could you optimize this further to get the most efficient algorithm for solving the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be transformed to a [maximum flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem).

**Transformation to a flow network**
Consider each element in either array $A$ or $B$ as a distinct node.
If element $e$ in $A$ can be mapped to element $k$ in $B$, add an edge from $e$ to $k$.
Add source node $s$. Add an edge from $s$ to each element in $A$.
Add sink node $t$. Add an edge from each element in $B$ to $t$.
Let the capacity of every edge be 1.
We have obtained $G$, a [flow network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network).

We can verify that the maximum number of mapped element in $A$ is exactly the maximal flow of $G$.

---

There are [many polynomial-time algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Algorithms) to compute the maximum flow of a flow-network. [Edmonds–Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) and [Dinic's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinic%27s_algorithm) are taught in many introductory course in graph algorithms. Implementations in various programming languages can be found readily online.

---

**Exercise 1.** Verify the maximum number of mapped element in $A$ is the maximal flow of $G$.

**Exercise 2.** The flow network that we constructed above, using one node for each element, is a unit-capacity flow network. To increase efficiency, describe how we can construct a new flow network using one node for each group of repeated elements instead, so that the maximum number of mapped element in $A$ is the maximal flow of the new flow network still.

Comment: The problem asks for the maximum matching of a bipartite graph. A more relevant reference could be [algorithms for bipartite graphs on maximum cardinality matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching). [Hopcroft–Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) can be a nice choice. (Just another different perspective.)